# How do I query a plist in objective c

Tags: objective-c

Is there a way to filter or query data in a plist. For example I want all objects that has Type='People'

Answer (score 3):

If you load your PList into an NSArray you can use `filteredArrayUsingPredicate:` along with an `NSPredicate` to perform filtering. For example:

```
NSBundle* bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString* path = [bundle pathForResource:@"data" ofType:@"plist"];
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:...];
NSString *type = @"People";
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Type == %@", type];
[array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Comment: I have a plist that has an array of dicts. in the dict there is a KEY with the name UID. I want to query the plist where UID="1234" .. will your code do that?

Comment: Try it. Also, in the future please include this in your original question.

Answer (score 1):

You can load the plist into dictionary and then get all values you want:

```
NSDictionary* dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile: @"someplist.plist"];
```